# changing chapter name in fncychap

Tags: chapters, fncychap

I am using the package `fncychap` ([here](http://ctan.unixbrain.com/macros/latex/contrib/fncychap/fncychap.pdf)) with scrbook and Sonny. Now I want to change the name of the word 'chapter' to a date which I can type by hand when I am creating a new chapter. I've experimented around with `\ChNameVar{}` but didn't get it. So how can you create this?

Comment: Like this? `\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[Sonny]{fncychap}

\newcommand\MyChap[1]{\renewcommand\chaptername{#1}}

\begin{document}

\MyChap{September 13}
\chapter{Test}

\end{document}`

Comment: @GonzaloMedina yes, it looks very nice. but is there any possibility to delete the chapter number?

Comment: Please see the answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Redefining `\DOCH` you can suppress the chapter numbering; the `\MyChap` command allows you to redefine `\chaptername` whenever needed:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[Sonny]{fncychap}

\newcommand\MyChap[1]{%
 \renewcommand\chaptername{#1}}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\DOCH}{%
    \raggedleft
    \CNV\FmN{\@chapapp}\space \CNoV
    \par\nobreak
    \vskip 40\p@}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\MyChap{September 13}
\chapter{Test title}

\end{document}
```

[image]

A new requirement has been made in a comment: to have the chapter title ragged right instead of ragged left; this can be accomplished with a redefinition of `\DOTI` and `\DOTIS`

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[Sonny]{fncychap}

\newcommand\MyChap[1]{%
 \renewcommand\chaptername{#1}}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\DOCH}{%
    \raggedleft
    \CNV\FmN{\@chapapp}\space \CNoV
    \par\nobreak
    \vskip 40\p@}
\renewcommand{\DOTI}[1]{%
    \CTV\raggedright\mghrulefill{\RW}\par\nobreak
    \vskip 5\p@
    \CTV\FmTi{#1}\par\nobreak
    \mghrulefill{\RW}\par\nobreak
    \vskip 40\p@}
  \renewcommand{\DOTIS}[1]{%
    \CTV\raggedright\mghrulefill{\RW}\par\nobreak
    \vskip 5\p@
    \CTV\FmTi{#1}\par\nobreak
    \mghrulefill{\RW}\par\nobreak
    \vskip 40\p@}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\MyChap{September 13}
\chapter{Test title}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: perfect! last question: is there any command to have 'Test title' on the right side and not on the left? I've tried some but all of them failed :/